# Long polling in minute or single scheduler for a task - Approach for a notification system

Tags: java, optimization, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a requirement in which, I will plan multiple tasks for certain interval. And for each task a notification has to be pushed at certain interval of time. 
I have two approaches, Either to write a single scheduler which will poll at each one minute and push the notification accordingly. Or I can schedule initialize a scheduler for each task. With the former method the solution is pretty much simple, with the later I can get more control on the scheduler, for instance I can put initial delay for each task specifically(Which is a requirement), then stop an individual task, resume etc. So far I am proceeding with the latter method. **But I would like to know If it could be better to use so many scheduler in a single application. Or is it better to go with a single scheduler with 1 minute polling?**. On an average I will have about 200+ tasks live at a time. Or for this can I depend on **any other library**?

So far my code 
**Sheduler** which is an ExecutorService

```
       //Constructor
            public TaskScheduler(String taskName) {
                this.taskName = taskName;
                this.taskResult = new TaskResult();
                this.taskResult.setStartTime(getNewDate());
                scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
//DB Operation
            }


    // To stop an individual task
                public TaskResult stop() throws InterruptedException {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Stopping : " + this.taskName);
                        this.taskResult.setTaskName(this.taskName);
                        this.taskResult.setEndTime(new Date());
                        scheduledFuture.cancel(false);
                        scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
//DB Operation 
                        System.out.println("Stopping : finished - " + this.taskName + " @ "+ new Date());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return this.taskResult;
                }

        //Portion to add task
            public TaskScheduler schedule(Runnable task, long initialDelay, long frequency) throws Exception{
                this.taskResult.setFrequencyInSeconds(frequency);
                scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, frequency, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                return this;
            }
```

**Task** thread with business logic

```
        public class TaskModel implements Runnable {
            private String taskName;

            public TaskModel() {

            }

            public TaskModel(String taskName) {
                this.taskName = taskName;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
//     DB operations
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use a single scheduler, but you don't need to write your own scheduler for this. You could use single instance `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)` with some number of threads to schedule all your tasks.

Think about the following code:

```
class TaskScheduler {
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    public TaskScheduler(int threads) {
        this.scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threads);
    }

    //Portion to add task
    public TaskExecutionContext schedule(String taskName, Runnable task, long initialDelay, long frequency) {
        TaskExecutionContext context = new TaskExecutionContext(taskName);
        context.getTaskResult().setFrequencyInSeconds(frequency);
        ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, frequency, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        context.setScheduledFuture(scheduledFuture);
        return context;
    }
}

class TaskExecutionContext {
    private String taskName;
    private TaskResult taskResult;

    private ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture;

    public TaskExecutionContext(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
        this.taskResult = new TaskResult();
        this.taskResult.setTaskName(taskName);
        this.taskResult.setStartTime(new Date());
        //DB Operation on creation
    }

    public TaskResult stop() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Stopping : " + this.taskName);
            this.taskResult.setTaskName(this.taskName);
            this.taskResult.setEndTime(new Date());
            scheduledFuture.cancel(false);
//DB Operation on stopping
            System.out.println("Stopping : finished - " + this.taskName + " @ " + new Date());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this.taskResult;
    }

    public TaskResult getTaskResult() {
        return this.taskResult;
    }

    public void setScheduledFuture(ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture) {
        this.scheduledFuture = scheduledFuture;
    }
}
```

If you need some extra operations on scheduling, creation and stopping tasks - probably, it's better to have separate `TaskExecutionContext`, which will perform all your needs.

Create a context when you need to schedule a task and pass it to scheduler.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed some points. Can you please have a look again. Also DB operations are included

Comment: In this case, I'd recommend using some task holder, which will contain a `future` and any task information. I've updated my answer.